# Organizing by rails datetime in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a scheduling app in Rails and I am getting stuck while trying to organize the rooms by date. When I say a room, I essentially just mean a block in the schedule. A typical event might have a lunch (one room), then a networking section (another room). Here is how I am getting the rooms:

```
@rooms = Room.where(event_id: @current_event.id).order(:start_time)
```

So that returns the rooms that belong to an event, in order of the start time. In my view I loop through and display the rooms for the event, but I want to group them in the view by the date in case there is an event that is on multiple days.

Also `:start_time` is a datetime type in Ruby. In human speak, what I would do is look at the date portion and if the room date is not the same as the current group, I would print the new date and continue to group the rooms that fall on that day. Here is a trivial example in case I am not being clear:

```
Event: Staff Retreat

July 14th, 2015
-----------------------
12:30 PM
Team building Lunch Begins
------------------------
6:30 PM
Team building Dinner Begins
------------------------

July 15th, 2015
------------------------
9:30 AM
Team building Breakfast Begins
```

So having the grouping of rooms in the `@rooms` variable that is a datetime, what would be the best way to display a table like the above? I would think that in my loop I should check if the date was the same as the previous room, and if not print the date

```
- @rooms.each do |room|
    room.start_time.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
    room.start_time.strftime("%I:%M%p")
    room.name
```

I am having trouble with the logistics because with the Model-View-Controller concept, I feel that sorting in the view may have the view do something it shouldn't have to. I am also struggling with how to do that in the view. I would think setting a variable in the controller that would hold the temporary date as I loop through would work, but it seems like that would start to get pretty messy though. What is the best way to group the various dates from the `@rooms` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this. this will return you a hash where date is the key and value will contain all the @rooms related to that time.

```
@rooms = Room.where(event_id: @current_event.id)
@rooms = Hash[@rooms.sort_by{|o| o.start_time.to_date}.group_by {|room| room.start_time.to_date}.map{|l,m| [l, m.sort_by{|k| k.start_time}]}]
```

now you can traverse the rooms like this in the views. im putting code in erb format.

```
  <% @rooms.each do |k, v| %>
     <%= k %>
     <% v.each do |room| %>
       <%= room.created_at.start_time('%I:%M %p')%>
       <%= #room.name or title what so ever. %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! That grouped them together just like I wanted but with one issue, the dates are out of order. One room is on the 7-13 which is first, then two rooms are on the 15th and those come second, then theres a room on the 14th that comes last, and the order is not the order they were created. I will post room model entries hoping that will help

Comment: name: "Room Test", created_at: "2015-07-13 20:03:08", updated_at: "2015-07-13 20:03:08", event_id: 1, start_time: "2015-07-13 17:30:00">, #<Room id: 15, name: "Lunch", created_at: "2015-07-15 13:43:37", updated_at: "2015-07-15 13:43:37", event_id: 1, start_time: "2015-07-15 11:30:00">, #<Room id: 16, name: "Test", created_at: "2015-07-15 14:08:44", updated_at: "2015-07-15 14:08:44", event_id: 1, start_time: "2015-07-14 10:30:00">, #<Room id: 17, name: "Same Day Event", created_at: "2015-07-15 16:42:23", updated_at: "2015-07-15 16:42:23", event_id: 1, start_time: "2015-07-15 14:30:00">]>

Comment: i have updated my answer . can you try now please . hope it will work

Comment: added sorting first to sort the rooms.

Comment: Great, thanks!! That completely solved it. Made it seem so simple to!